# serverUrl for Apex Web Service

Tags: apex, soap-api, webservices

When using the enterprise WSDL, we use the dynamic serverUrl that's returned from the login for subsequent calls using the ent wsdl.  What do others do for custom Apex services for the endpoint?  I know you *can* use the endpoint from the wsdl definition but is that best practice?  Should we be constructing the endpoint using a portion of the serverUrl returned from the login or just using the static endpoints from the custom wsdl when using Apex services?

This is being used in Oracle SOA 11g if it makes a difference.

Comment: Using the dynamic serverUrl returned from the login is the Right Thing.

Comment: I agree...but how to get it for the custom service? Do you recommend deconstructing the serverUrl and prepending?

Comment: _Custom_ service - beg your pardon indeed! IMHO your prepending of the serverUrl is preferable; saves one regenerating the WSDL to get the `soap:address` for sandboxes etc.

Comment: Thanks for the validation, that's what I was thinking. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to do this is to get the *serverUrl* login result get the hostname and use that for the endpoint for the custom WSDL.

*Making this a formal answer to help out*